# NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, security, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have generated self signed certificate for my server. After importing root CA cert to my browser, I was trying to access my website via Chrome, I am however getting "NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" error. Is there a way to 'debug' Chrome's certs procedure so that I could find out what I am doing wrong when generating the cert ?

The error is very vague and makes me run in circles tweaking portions of the script I wrote to make it work ... without luck.

Here is the script (I have changed certs subject details for security purposes ;-) )

```
echo "Removing existing files ..."
rm root*
rm server*
rm v3*

echo "Step 1"
printf "  authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer\n  basicConstraints=CA:FALSE\n  
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, 
dataEncipherment\n  subjectAltName = @alt_names\n\n  [alt_names]\n  IP.1 = 
"$1 > v3.ext

echo "Step 2"
openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 2048

echo "Step 3"
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out 
rootCA.pem -subj 
"/C=US/ST=PA/L=Pittsburgh/O=TestTest/OU=TestTest/CN=www.test.com"

echo "Step 4"
openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out server.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout 
server.key -subj "/C=US/ST=PA/L=Pittsburgh/O=ServerCert/OU=ServerCert/CN=$1"

echo "Step 5"
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -
CAcreateserial -out server.pem -days 500 -sha256 -extfile v3.ext
```

IE uses the same repository for root certificates as Chrome, but it does validate my cert successfully.